# looking for saying about getting happy with other faults and getting sad with others success

Tags: word-usage, expressions

I want to write a saying or good expression in an email to my boss to say "we should not be happy of other company's fault and get sad if they get better. we should be happy with what we are doing".

I wanted to say "Stronger enemies makes us stronger" but I was not sure if this really fits to the case? or is there any better sentences for that?

Answer (score 1):

If we were trying to say that we'll all get better if everyone succeeds, we could use this expression:

> **Together everyone achieves more**

Appropriately enough, when written out as an acronym, that spells out the word TEAM:

[image]

---

However, your situation is a little different. Your question reminds me of the famous saying:

> **What doesn't kill you makes you stronger**.

This maxim has worked its way into pop culture, via [internet memes, song lyrics, and t-shirts](https://www.google.com/search?safe=off&site=imghp&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1502&bih=776&q=what%20doesn%27t%20kill%20you%20makes%20you%20stronger).

For the corporate environment, you could simply pluralize the pronouns:

> **What doesn't kill us makes us stronger**.

and if you didn't like the word "kill," you could alter it a little more:

> **What doesn't defeat us makes us better**.

Comment: As you said, it is not exactly what I was looking for. Specially, because by "other people", I mean the other company's people. We basically are not a TEAM :)

Comment: @mmostajab - Ah, I see. Your edit makes that clearer now. I will have to rethink this.